# How do I justify strings in a listbox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-3.0

I am binding values to list box but string not showing in proper format.

ex my strings like

```
abc               10
abcd              20
asdfas            30
```

I made fixed length to first string that is 30 using padding

```
str1.PadRight(30) + str2.PadRight(2)
```

then also I am getting values like that

```
abc     10
abcd        20
asdfas            30
```

Please suggest how can I put same space between string

Comment: One problem is that you're probably not using a fixed width font.

Comment: Try to set the Font property of the ListBox to FixedSys.

Comment: Yes, use a fixed width font or use a multi-column listview or grid control instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows User Interface usually uses a variable-width font, so you can't just pad with spaces to a given column to get the text to line up.

You will either need to set the ListBox to use a monospaced font (Courier or Lucida Console for example), use a ListView (or similar) that supports columns, or implement owner-drawn items so that you can control how the items are displayed, splitting up the text to drawing it in columns.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms `ListBox` supports multiple columns. There's an example right there in the documentation for the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.listbox%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Although this might not work with data binding. In which case, you'll probably need to use a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a ViewModel wrapping the text and a number:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then give the `ListBox` an `ItemTemplate` that does the layout:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                           Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                           Text="{Binding Number}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```